# Trying to click on the sign in button through python

Tags: python, html, authentication, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image: imgofhtml]

## Locate and click the "Sign In" button

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    accept_cookies_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "truste-consent-button")))
    accept_cookies_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error accepting cookies:", e)
# Wait for the "Sign In" button to become clickable
# Locate and click the "Sign In" button
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span")

    # Perform actions on the element (e.g., click)
    element.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Sign In button not found")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for the Sign In button to become clickable")
```

I am trying to click on the sign in button using python, I have used both the xpath and css selector options but the bot will not click on it. I am importing a webdriver through selenium to do this. The website itself does not have a different url when the sign in button is clicked but it does have a different html structure. The code is highlighting the sign in button but not clicking on it

Comment: where's your wait? and have you tried `//a[@title="Sign In"]` as the XPATH?

Comment: I edited the initial post to show wait, and tried that. The code highlights the sign in button but does not click on it.

Comment: would be able to provide the working solution if you could share the URL

Comment: The URL is https://gb.sparex.com/

Comment: @keelan99 I tried your edited code. The problem is that sign in seems to be disabled or something in the selenium window - it's physically no longer possible to click it. It might be a measure against bots.